# ¿Como saco la informacion almacenada en get() tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

¿De qué forma puedo sacar lo almacenado en `get()` numero por numero y carácter por carácter?

```
carácter_pantalla.set(caracter_pantalla.get() + numero)
```

Por ejemplo si `get()` tubiera alamcenado lo siguente:

> 345+24+14

si hago un ciclo for me da así:

```
for i in caracter_pantalla.get(): print(i)
```

Resultado:

> 3 4 5 + 2 4 + 1 4

Necesito que los bote asi:

> 345 + 24 + 14

Answer (score 0):

En vez de recorrer cada caracter en el bucle puedes crear una lista mediante el **método split** a partir de tu *string*. Recorre los elementos de dicha lista:

```py
lista = caracter_pantalla.get().split('+')

i = 0
while i < len(lista):
    print(lista[i])
    if i != len(lista) - 1:
        print('+')
    i += 1
```